# Automatically update Jira ticket / create new Jira ticket based on Excel file - using python script

Tags: python, excel, jira, python-jira

I would like to update/create everything in Excel file, but want to update/create Jira tickets automatically, using Python.

1.) Use the information from excel file and **create tickets automatically** in JIRA.

2.) **Update an existing Jira ticket automatically** with changes in the Excel file.

Could you maybe give me some help how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow

Maintaining Jira issues and creating them through Excel is a great idea, however there are many moving parts to it, and it won't be easy to be developed as python script as it is more like a **small project**.

If you are looking for quick and easy solution check this out:
[Excel 365 Connector for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222961/excel-365-connector-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this very thing, I think I've covered the basics of what you are looking to do in this project - https://github.com/dren79/JiraScripting_public
The functionality is there, I do need to tidy up the README and comments. Let me know if you get done what you need to accomplish.